# Poetry commands not running because of gunicorn, even after its installed and updated

Tags: python, dependencies, python-poetry

I'm trying to run a program developed by one of my teammates, but for no apparent reason the poetry commands are not working because of **gunicorn**.

```
theiago@Theiago:~/kuhlenbier_webapi_tap$ poetry lock
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (2.7s)

Because kuhlenbier-api depends on gunicorn (^20.2.0) which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
```

But when I check gunicorn, it's installed and updated:

```
theiago@Theiago:~/kuhlenbier_webapi_tap$ gunicorn --version
gunicorn (version 21.2.0)
```

Comment: What version of Python and poetry are you using? Is that all of the output that poetry produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you, that the project depends on `gunicorn` within the version range of `^20.2.0`.This is equivalent to `>=20.2.0,<21.0`. If you have look at [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/gunicorn/#history) you will see that there is no version, that fulfill this range.

I guess you've install gunicorn before in some other way, e.g. by `pip`.

Run `poetry add gunicorn@latest` to add the latest version your project. This should fix your issue.